# What title describes people who setup and customize web applications?

Tags: web-applications, saas

In today's world of SAAS, many web applications are becoming highly customizable. The amount of configuration options are often so many that it can take years to fully understand all their ramifications. Some software even enables you to add fields or even whole new forms. Some even develop into full platforms that you can create nearly entire applications without writing a single line of code.

This is kind of like programming because you really have to understand computers but you're not actually writing code. Most companies I've worked at have a group of these. What do you call them?

Answer (score 0):

So, for example, you're wondering what you might call someone who is excellent with a tool like Yahoo Pipes?

"Application designer" or "application architect" comes to mind, since this kind of work usually involves abstract modelling of software, without actually writing any code. For instance, the logic in a a Yahoo Pipe could be compared to creating a UML diagram in the sense that you are planning logic.

This is just my interpretation and I'm sure there are a lot of people who would argue semantics with me.

Comment: Yes Yahoo Pipes is a good example. Also, web applications such as Salesforce.com, Drupal, Word Press, Joomla, JIRA, Confluence, and even SAP and Peoplesoft are examples of applications with a wide enough array of options that it can take a person months, years or even decades to master.